# Message with no body sent in magento at new order placed

Tags: php, magento

When i place an order , the order placed email is successfully sent but with no message body. the subject seems to be correct as it is in my template selected for the place new order mail.
please help, how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First step

1. Go to `System > Transactional Email`
2. Press `Add new template`
3. In `Template` dropbox select `New Order` (i think that in your case it's correct)
4. Select Locale and press `Load template`
5. Fill data in `Template Information`
6. Save template

Second step

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Sales Emails > Order`
2. In `New Order Confirmation Template` dropbox select template which you created in **First step**

Check now if you're still getting empty confirmation email.

Answer (score 2):

If the body of the email is blank, it sounds like there is an error occurring in the code that generates it.

Look through your system.log and exception.log for errors. See [here](http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-error-logs/) for details on how to set this up if you are unsure.

If nothing is showing up, then do as @Lrrr suggested, if you are still getting a blank body, then start taking pieces out of the template until you see a non-blank body...this will then help identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: yes it looks like there is some error in coding because the email is sent successfully but with no message body. can u please tell me where should i check for this . i mean where it would be setting the message before sending the email. which file should i look into to fix it up.

Comment: From my diggings I believe the actual send function is call `sendTransactional` and it's in the `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` file. It looks like it calls on `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` to handle the processing of the variables in the template